# javascript and div ids

Tags: javascript, html

If i have the following code in my html file

```
<div id=div1> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    externalFunction();
</script>
```

Is it possible to get the id of the div in the method externalFunction()?

Regards
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the id? Name is different. The short answer is no, the longer answer is you can if you know something about the div you are looking for ( such as the class or where it's located or anything else.)

Comment: yeah i was figuring  the same. its not a big thing, the user can pass the divId in. I was just trying to help out lazy users thats all. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to simply get the `div` without actually referencing the `id` you could do the following in jQuery:

```
$("div").each(function() {
   // Do stuff.
});
```

This would essentially loop around each of the `divs` on the page, it would then be up to your `externalFunction()` to handle each `div` accordingly.

And for when jQuery isn't an option:

```
var divElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i=0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
   var currDiv = divElements[i]; // Do stuff with the element.
}
```